# How to allow text selection in TideSDK

Tags: tidesdk

I'm developing an app for use with TideSDK. Obviously, in Chrome, the user can select any html text he sees. However, in TideSDK, it appears that text selection is disabled by default. I imagine a simple setting will allow it, but after Googling and looking in the documentation, I can't find anything to show how to allow the user to select text. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: No ideas, eh? Not even one?

Answer (score 1):

```
body, p
{
    -webkit-user-select: auto;
}
```

I tried the code above. it worked...

By default the body loads the -webkit-user-select: auto; in body section of tideSDK so the contents are not selectable

Answer (score 0):

Found the [answer](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/122867/how-to-enable-user-selection-on-a-div-titanium-desktop). You must use `-webkit-user-select: auto|text` for the element you want to be selectable. Not sure why text is not selectable by default.